# c# build error: error X2230 the type x is in assembly y that needs to be referenced

Tags: c#, build, build-process, build-automation

Getting following build error:

> error X2230: the type 'ASA.Log.ServiceLogger.IASALog' is in assembly
>   'ASA.Log.ServiceLogger' that needs to be referenced

Here's the scenario:

1) Only fails to build when do a Build/Rebuild Solution in Visual Studio (I have run clean multiple times)

2) The .DLL doesn't seem to be in the GAC

3) This is a clean "build" machine, we are working on setting up automated builds.  It compiles fine on developers machines.

4) When I click on the error, it doesn't take me anywhere.  It doesn't specify the line of code or even the related project.  I have a bunch of C# and BizTalk projects in the same solution.  By scanning the code/text on disk, I think I know which project it is.  But each C# project builds successfully when built by itself.

5) The DLL being referenced is from another internal group (i.e. I don't have the code and cannot build it).  I copied a new version of the referenced DLL from another machine's GAC to the library from where I'm referencing it.  One theory was that I had an out of date DLL, i.e. that the GAC on the dev machines was current, but the DLL being referenced was not.

So I'm stuck and don't know how to get the build to complete.

Meanwhile, I'll go try FusLogVw, but would rather not install extra junk on this build machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I had felt sure that the error was in one of the C# projects, but in frustration, I started building each of the 12 or so BizTalk projects.  Finally, I found another project that had a "GAC" reference, and changed it to a disk/library reference, and life is good.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of the assemblies that you reference in turn references ASA.Log.ServiceLogger.dll which is not available.  You should be able to get this dependency from the group that shipped the assembly that depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your build machine dos not contain this missing reference in the GAC (Point 2 in your question). It compiles fine on developers machines (point 3). My suggestion is to add missing reference into the GAC.